# Vimeo embed code not working on IE11

Tags: internet-explorer, vimeo

I have been working on this issue for several days and done endless research on the net but still can't resolve it. The vimeo universal embed code works beautifully on everything but IE on 10 & 11 windows7. It shows up as a black screen, I can see the controls and it seems to play on Windows 8 IE is working. The old code works well on everything but doesn't show up on the ipad.

I tried using both  and  and then using conditional statements to display:none; on non IE browsers. After searching to find that IE 10 & 11 don't recognize conditional statements any more.

I have tried hosting my own .webm, mp4, ogv with a flash fallback but the streaming was terrible so I created a plus account in vimeo thinking I would save myself time. After reading lots of forums I was wondering if anyone had an answer or recommended solution I could try.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: I figured this out myself. Thanks

Comment: Mich376, what was your solution?

Comment: I found out that there was an option not selected, in internet options-advanced-'use software rendering' needs to be ticked. Really annoyed it was something so simple I spent days trying to figure out why.

Comment: Ah yes. Did some more googling and found this Vimeo article: https://vimeo.com/forums/help/topic:112861

Comment: Thanks for that, I'm surprised I didn't find that article myself! Cheers

Answer (score 3):

This is due to a browser issue with hardware vs software acceleration. Vimeo explains more here ([Vimeo Forums: Playback Issues on Windows](https://vimeo.com/forums/help/topic:112861)) but the short of it is:

> These issues do not affect all users of [Windows Chrome/IE/FF]
>   browsers, and they are not in Vimeo's power to resolve because they
>   pertain to the way the latest versions of Chrome and Firefox decode
>   HTML5 video on particular Windows machines.
>
> ... In the meantime, you may be able to resolve them yourself by
>   **disabling hardware acceleration** in your browser.

Mich376 figured this out himself, but then drove us to this article. For easier finding, it's now here in a solution.

Answer (score -1):

This was one of the threads I looked at while troubleshooting this issue, but a different solution worked for me.

The original Vimeo embed code I placed on the page had the url like this:

//player.vimeo.com/video/[...]

without the "https:" -- when I added the "https:," it fixed the problem and the videos now play in all browsers.

In other words, if you have a URL that starts like this "//player.vimeo.com/video/," try changing it to: "https://player.vimeo.com/video/"